# how to navigate from one view to another without navigation? in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Tour.m:

```
-(void)loadViewMonthArr:(NSMutableArray*)arr
{
    if ([arr count]) {
        self.selectedDate=(NSDate*)[arr objectAtIndex:0];
   //     [slider setselectedbuttonfordate:self.selectedDate];
        NSDateFormatter *form=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [form setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd"];

        [(UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:7600]setText:[form stringFromDate:self.selectedDate]];
        [form setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
        [(UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:7601]setText:[form stringFromDate:self.selectedDate]];
        NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [form setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];


        form=nil;
      arr=nil;
    }


    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Pie" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:NO];

    monthlyCalendar.hidden = YES;
    New_Retailer.view.hidden = NO;
    [New_Retailer LoadNewRetailer];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:New_Retailer.view];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

in tour class I got calendar with dates. when i tap the particular date how can navigate tour to newretailer_tour class withoutusing navigation controler?.

i am going LoadNewRetailer method. method is working. but newretailer_tour.xib i setted blue background color. when i run app, when i tap the date,it is going to newretailer_tour class method. but, in simulator i am not getting color newretailer_tour class. suuggest me

Comment: Is newretailler_tour a UIViewController?

Answer (score 0):

```
SecondViewController *navigate=[[SecondViewController  alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self presentViewController:navigate animated:YES completion:^(void){}];
```

Comment: thanks for ur idea.i dont want to use present modal view controller. can you give another idea?. when i tap this date,this view will hide,nnewretailer_tour class will active. I want to create like that. thanks in advance

Comment: dude can u give more information , what actually u want to ask

Answer (score 0):

just use present modalview controller.It will present view controller.Andthen add one toolbar to your view and then one back button.On clicking back button just dismiss modal view controller.I think this will do it for you.

Comment: thanks for ur idea.i dont want to use present modal view controller. can you give another idea?. when i tap this date,this view will hide,nnewretailer_tour class will active. I want to create like that. thanks in advance

Comment: Create One segment controller.Add bar button for the view.just try to add one view for the segment button.And try to show the dateview on first button and show the another view on clicking another button.Just try to add toolbar or segment bar and maintain the views.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use,

> presentViewController

or you would manually add the viewcontrollers view to your existing view.

> YourVC *vcObject=[[YourVC  alloc]initWithNibName:@"YourVC"
> bundle:nil];
>
> [existingVC addSubview:vcObject.view];

You could also add some animation while adding it as a subview.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Pie" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:vcObject.view] cache:NO];
[existingVC addSubview:vcObject.view];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

For giving only effect of navigation controller you can use `modalTransitionStyle`

For Example,

```
   [self setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve]
[self presentModalViewController:<#(UIViewController *)#> animated:<#(BOOL)#>];
```

Comment: As you are against editing your answers, just that `presentModalViewController:animated:` is deprecated. Rather use `presentViewController:animated:completion:` method. Now it is up to you whether you want to edit it or not. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @ParthBhatt. I know it's deprecated. But I gave answer by keeping the goal in mind that is modaltransitionstyle, which is important regarding to the question. & Thus I wrote the old method according to the normal practice.